# Will it be slower if a unique index added while creating a table from a select with group by?

Tags: mysql, group-by, create-table, unique-index

I am creating a table with the following select query:

```
create table mytable(
  anInt int,
  aVarchar varchar(100)
) engine=MyISAM
select count(*) anInt, aVarchar from temptable
group by 2
```

Will it be any slower if i add a unique index on `aVarchar` in the table definition of `mytable`? I think mysql should be clever enough to figure out it's already unique due to `group by 2`.

Comment: Generally I would expect such a query to be quick enough that any difference would be nominal compared with how often you create the table (assuming it isn't a temp table being created all over the place). I would be more worried about whether an unique  index is required when reading the table / updating the table.